# Generate content with servlet into iframe which is inside another html

Tags: html, servlets, iframe, load

I'm learning Servlet now, and I was wondering if it is possible to generate 2 html content at once. I would like to generate an html page which is holding an iframe which also has a content. Is it possible to load 2 html page at once in Servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is completely possible. All you have to do is complete your code for html page which is going to be displayed in the iframe.

Now in servlet you have to write the html code for displaying and call the iframe in servlet. 
So when your servlet will run on the server it will be running html code of servlet + iframe (which is displaying another html content)